# alternative to collision detection?

Tags: java, graphics, collision-detection, 2d-games

I need to check the collision between the area `a` and the area `b`:

```
Area a = new Area(new Ellipse2D.Float(100, 100, 70, 70));
Area b = new Area(new Polygon(x,y,n));
```

Where `x` and `y` are arrays that store the polygon's coordinates. I tried:

```
boolean checkCollision()
{
    a.intersect(b);
    return !a.isEmpty();
}
```

Finally I wrote this method to see if it works:

```
public String toString()
{
    if(checkCollision())
        return "TOUCH";
    else
        return "NO TOUCH";
}
```

This method does not seem to be working: When I touch the vertices of the polygon, it does not detect the collision.

[image]
[image]

> [image]

In the 3rd picture you can see that only if I am "far enough" from the areas they don't collide (the polygon is white in these pictures). If they are near, instead, the collision is not very accurate, it seems not to be working.

Is this method the right way to do it? Any suggestions? Alternatives?

Comment: Please post the actual code necessary to reproduce this.

Comment: I think this is enough.. after this I draw it and I move the ball, but this is not inportant in colliision.. Whatever if you would like more I will add more.

Comment: This is not working code. We can't check if the problem is in the way that you have implemented it (my first guess) or if there is an actual problem in the collision detection.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong. But from first research, your intersects call doesn't make any sense: Given [Area-Doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Area.html), the intersects is only defined with a `Rectangle2D` as a single parameter.

Comment: The pictures confuse me. In picture 2, the ball is completely on the black area and does intersect while in picture 3 it's on the black area completely as well and does not intersect. Is there a border below the screenshot in picture 3, or what scenario do you wish to describe with each of the pictures?

Comment: That is the problem!! I cannot understand why It says "TOUCH" in the 2nd picture..

Comment: @MalaKa it is intersect not intersects*!! sorry it is my fault!

Comment: @MArivs Then it still is an issue since - as given in [intersect-doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Area.html#intersect%28java.awt.geom.Area%29), this method has no return value. The code shouldn't even compile.

Comment: I added better images

Comment: Ofcourse it compiles! there are 2 areas: and **area1.intersect(area2)**  returns a _boolean _!! In fact it works between ellipses!

Comment: Anyway, If it is not correct just suggest me what to do!! I am not a professional programmer like you! :) So maybe I do the things in the wrong way!

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Area.html#intersect(java.awt.geom.Area) - that does not do what you expect it to do.

Comment: @LordAnomander you were right.. I forgot to wrtite a line of code in **checkCollision()**!! I wrote it without taking a look to my code .. now it should be the right one!! thank you